# Lighting Fast CMS, a Django based CMS. Any experiences?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system

I've just came across Lighting Fast CMS, which seems to be very promising Django based content management system. Documentation seem to be very good, even though it is still in beta stage. It also has very nice buildout based installation. Also  the core Components of it seem to be nicely decoupled.

Does anyone have any experiences with it yet?

How much one can customize it with extensions?

How's extension development in general compared to Drupal or Plone?

I'm hoping that I could do some projects with it instead of Plone or Drupal. Those both are great, but extending them ain't too nice.

The project can be found here:
http://www.lfcproject.com/

Comment: This looks like it's from the makers of http://www.getlfs.com/ (the LFS django shopping cart)

Answer (score -1):

I do not know anything about lfc, but you can also give django-cms a try!
http://www.django-cms.org

Comment: Yes true :)
But if you dont know it yet, try it out, I have some good experiences with it, like the plug in concept of it and it also supports multiple sites...

Comment: Yeah, I have tried django-cms- After few minutes of poking around with both, I do find LFC bit more polished. At least just after installation it is just more user friendly. It is also a hole lot more easier to install!